# Why is the "largest" variable set to None if it can also be set to 0?

Tags: python

I was reading a pdf so that I could learn python however I still don't really understand "None". Here is the code:

```
largest = None
print('Before:', largest)
for itervar in [3, 41, 12, 9, 74, 15]:
    if largest is None or itervar > largest :
        largest = itervar
    print('Loop:', itervar, largest)
print('Largest:', largest)
```

I replaced the "None" with 0 instead and the code worked completely fine. So why would you not use 0 instead?

Comment: What if all the values are negative?

Comment: Ideally, you'd use `float("-inf")` anyway and remove `is None` check

Comment: another great value of working with `None` is that it's easy to get an Exception when a value is unset or to check and see if a value was never set (simply checking, or letting a compare against it fail), which improves code quality and adds a meaningful escape from doing more work in a function on an invalid input

Comment: I actually didn't think about that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ideally, just do `largest = input_list[0]` and then iterate over `input_list[1:]`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Not if the list is empty ;)

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's a problem in any case... If we do `largest = float("-inf")` we'll get the result as `"Largest: -inf"`... Also problematic...

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I think the current code is better - its faster.Using `float` means that each integer in `itervar` needs to be converted to a float temporarily for the compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None` just indicates that you haven't looked at any value yet. (If you had, one of them would be the value of `largest`, not `None`.)

`0` works as an initial value *if* your list contains at least one non-negative value. Otherwise, you'll get an odd result like "0 is the largest value in `[-1, -2]`" or "0 is the largest value in `[]`".

Answer (score 0):

This is a common way of setting a default value. `None` is a singleton, meaning there is only one `None` and using 'is' always works as you'd expect. `is` is very fast, much faster than equality tests. With `is`, python just tests the memory address of the operands. With equality, python has to call one of the object's magic methods (`__eq__`, etc..).

Singletons are rare in python, even integers like `1000` are not singletons and should generally not be used with `is`. [Note: cpython does use singletons for a small set of integers around zero, but that is an implementation detail, not a guarantee]

So, you find yourself in a situation where a variable could hold any integer, but you need a special case when the variable doesn't have an integer assigned to it yet. `None` is fast, so its a good match. That holds for any class type where you also need a default for the variable.

Its not always necessary. Your example could have been written several ways. But its a good use of `None`.